# $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{iz+i}$ maps any circle passing through $-1$ to a line

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f: \mathbb{C}\backslash\{-1\} \to \mathbb{C},\  f(z)=\frac{z-1}{iz+i}$ maps any circle passing through $-1$ to a line.

I want to find an expression for $z$ so that $z$ can be on any circle passing through $-1$.

Comment: Do you know how to find a circle equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple. Note taht $f$ is a Moebius map, then it maps circles(intended in the Riemann sphere) in circles.
Now $iz+i=0$ when $z=-1$ then the point $\infty$ is in the immage of your circle. If a circle in the Riemann sphere has the point $\infty$ it is a line in the plane.

Comment: I quite understand what you mean. But why "if a circle in the Riemann sphere has the point $\infty$ it is a line in the plane"?